# Adding message to assert

Tags: c++, logging, debugging, assert

I'm looking for a way to add custom messages to assert statements.
I found this questions [Add custom messages in assert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692954/add-custom-messages-in-assert) but the message is static there. I want to do something like this:

```
assert((0 < x) && (x < 10), std::string("x was ") + myToString(x));
```

When the assertion fails I want the normal output plus for example "x was 100".

Comment: I think here you have better [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692954/add-custom-messages-in-assert)

Comment: Ugly hack: `if (fail_condition) assert(!"My message");`

Comment: @MarkKCowan , I think that your "ugly hack" is actually way better than the "&&" patch up, because it only shows the message :)

Comment: Isn't one issue with @MarkKCowan's hack is that once you `#define NDEBUG` for your release code (to remove asserts) your code will still be evaluating potentially costly conditions? Would the compiler know to optimise away an empty `if`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You are out of luck here. The best way is to define your own `assert` macro.

Basically, it can look like this:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define ASSERT(condition, message) \
    do { \
        if (! (condition)) { \
            std::cerr << "Assertion `" #condition "` failed in " << __FILE__ \
                      << " line " << __LINE__ << ": " << message << std::endl; \
            std::terminate(); \
        } \
    } while (false)
#else
#   define ASSERT(condition, message) do { } while (false)
#endif
```

This will define the `ASSERT` macro only if the no-debug macro `NDEBUG` isn’t defined.

Then you’d use it like this:

```
ASSERT((0 < x) && (x < 10), "x was " << x);
```

Which is a bit simpler than your usage since you don’t need to stringify `"x was "` and `x` explicitly, this is done implicitly by the macro.

Comment: Why the do { } while (false) ?

Comment: @tauran: So you can put a semicolon after the macro when using it.

Comment: Why not a `do { } while (false)` for the `#else` case? ;-) Also often useful to display the stringified assertion source code `#condition`. Strictly, EXIT_FAILURE should be preferred over 1 too.  +1 as it's shaping up as the best answer.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that `asm("int 3")` is more appropriate for an assert macro than `exit()`?

Comment: Probably not so much `asm("int 3")`, but `abort()` might be better.

Comment: @Jon: depends. Keep in mind that the `asm` one isn't portable (and on a MS compiler, won't even work in 64-builds), but also that depending on when, where and how you run the code, you might not want it to trigger a breakpoint. (MS has the `__debugbreak` intrinsic though, which works on all MS platforms) Ideally, you could make the macro configurable, so the developer can switch between aborting and breaking on assert at compile-time or at runtime

Comment: I see that on macosx __assert() uses abort() for debug break. Does abort() exist on windows?

Comment: Why not just {} to make it a code block? Why the do while?

Comment: @Martin Because then the macro use has to be terminated with a semi-colon, which is exactly what we want. Using `do…while` in macros is therefore an established pattern.

Comment: You should use abort() or throw an exception instead of using exit().

Comment: @whoKnows Correct, although `std::terminate` is probably a more C++-y substitute of `std::abort` (though it by default calls the latter). In my own programs I usually just throw an unhandleable exception but that would make this answer longer without tangible benefit.

Answer (score 42):

There are some old tricks to include messages without writing your own routines:

The first is this:

```
bool testbool = false;
assert(("this is the time", testbool));
```

There is also:

```
bool testbool = false;
assert(testbool && "This is a message");
```

The first one works, because the inside parens expression result is the value of 'testbool'.
The second one works, because the value of the string is going to be non-zero.

Comment: Note that `assert((<cond>) && "msg");` causes CppCheck (v1.90) to generate an "incorrectStringBooleanError" warning

Comment: @ahogen You might try casting the string to an int or bool to see if that quiets the messages, although maybe it would complain about the cast in that case. Let me know if you find a workaround.  Did the first method work satisfactorily for CppCheck?

Answer (score 12):

A better alternative is to teach the debugger to stop on assert when it fails, then you could examine not only the x value but any other information including call stack. Perhaps, this is what you are really looking for. 
Sample implementation is mentioned here [Ways to show your co-programmers that some methods are not yet implemented in a class when programming in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314314/ways-to-show-your-co-programmers-that-some-methods-are-not-yet-implemented-in-a-c/3316954#3316954)

Comment: I conquer, although there is the fact that you may not be at your console to debug the issue. But in that case, I would want to log the error, not just get a message on the screen.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define ASSERT_WITH_MESSAGE(condition, message) do { \
if (!(condition)) { printf((message)); } \
assert ((condition)); } while(false)
```

Comment: This evaluates the condition twice which may cause the condition to change: `ASSERT_WITH_MESSAGE(++i == 10, "Ten")`

Answer (score 6):

Extending on Kondrad Rudolph's answer:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(condition, message) 0
#else
#define assert(condition, message)\
   (!(condition)) ?\
      (std::cerr << "Assertion failed: (" << #condition << "), "\
      << "function " << __FUNCTION__\
      << ", file " << __FILE__\
      << ", line " << __LINE__ << "."\
      << std::endl << message << std::endl, abort(), 0) : 1
#endif

void foo() {
   int sum = 0;
   assert((sum = 1 + 1) == 3, "got sum of " << sum << ", but expected 3");
}

int main () {
   foo();
}
```

Output is...

```
Assertion failed: ((sum = 1 + 1) == 3), function foo, file foo.cpp, line 13.
got sum of 2, but expected 3
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

which is similar to what the std::assert macro outputs on my system just with the additional user defined message

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, I published a drop-in 2 files assert macro implementation in C++:

```
#include <pempek_assert.h>

int main()
{
  float min = 0.0f;
  float max = 1.0f;
  float v = 2.0f;
  PEMPEK_ASSERT(v > min && v < max,
                "invalid value: %f, must be between %f and %f", v, min, max);

  return 0;
}
```

Will prompt you with:

```
Assertion 'v > min && v < max' failed (DEBUG)
  in file e.cpp, line 8
  function: int main()
  with message: invalid value: 2.000000, must be between 0.000000 and 1.000000

Press (I)gnore / Ignore (F)orever / Ignore (A)ll / (D)ebug / A(b)ort:
```

Where

- (I)gnore: ignore the current assertion
- Ignore (F)orever: remember the file and line where the assertion fired and
  ignore it for the remaining execution of the program
- Ignore (A)ll: ignore all remaining assertions (all files and lines)
- (D)ebug: break into the debugger if attached, otherwise `abort()` (on Windows,
  the system will prompt the user to attach a debugger)
- A(b)ort: call `abort()` immediately

You can find out more about it there:

- [blog post](http://pempek.net/articles/2013/11/17/cross-platform-cpp-assertion-library/)
- [GitHub project](https://github.com/gpakosz/Assert)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

To enable expression like `better_assert((0 < x) && (x < 10), std::string("x was ") + myToString(x));`, we are supposed to have a corresponding macro in a form of

```
#define better_assert(EXPRESSION, ... ) ((EXPRESSION) ? \
(void)0 : print_assertion(std::cerr, \
"Assertion failure: ", #EXPRESSION, " in File: ", __FILE__, \ 
" in Line: ", __LINE__ __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__))
```

in which `print_assertion` is a proxy function to do the assertion. When the `EXPRESSION` is evaluated `false`, all the debug information, the `__VA_ARGS__`, will be dumped to `std::cerr`. This function takes arbitrary numbers of arguments, thus we should implement a variadic templated function:

```
template< typename... Args >
void print_assertion(std::ostream& out, Args&&... args)
{
    out.precision( 20 );
    if constexpr( debug_mode )
    {
        (out << ... << args) << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}
```

In the previous implementation, the expression `(out << ... << args) << std::endl;` make use of fold expression in C++17 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold); the constant expression `debug_mode` is related to the compilation options passed, which is can be defined as

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    constexpr std::uint_least64_t debug_mode = 0;
#else
    constexpr std::uint_least64_t debug_mode = 1;
#endif
```

It also worth mentioning that the expression `if constexpr( debug_mode )` makes use of constexpr if (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) imported since C++17.

To wrap everything up, we have:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    constexpr std::uint_least64_t debug_mode = 0;
#else
    constexpr std::uint_least64_t debug_mode = 1;
#endif

template< typename... Args >
void print_assertion(std::ostream& out, Args&&... args)
{
    out.precision( 20 );
    if constexpr( debug_mode )
    {
        (out << ... << args) << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}
#ifdef better_assert
#undef better_assert
#endif
#define better_assert(EXPRESSION, ... ) ((EXPRESSION) ? (void)0 : print_assertion(std::cerr, "Assertion failure: ",  #EXPRESSION, " in File: ", __FILE__, " in Line: ",  __LINE__ __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__))
```

A typical test case demonstrating its usage can be:

```
double const a = 3.14159265358979;
double const b = 2.0 * std::asin( 1.0 );
better_assert( a==b, " a is supposed to be equal to b, but now a = ", a, " and b = ", b );
```

This will produce something error message like:

```
Assertion failure: a==b in File: test.cc in Line: 9 a is supposed to be equal to b, but now a = 3.1415926535897900074 and b = 3.141592653589793116
[1]    8414 abort (core dumped)  ./test
```

And the full source code is available in this repo: https://github.com/fengwang/better_assert

Answer (score 1):

To take on Feng Wang answer, in newer versions of C++, anything inline is going to be optimized out. So you can have an inline function in a header file which does all the work.

```
inline constexpr void NOT_USED()
{
}

template <class T, class ...ARGS>
inline constexpr void NOT_USED(T && first, ARGS && ...args)
{
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-result"
    static_cast<void>(first);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    NOT_USED(args...);
}

template<typename ... ARGS>
void SAFE_ASSERT(bool test_result, ARGS &&... args)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    if(test_result)
    {
        (std::cerr << ... << args) << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
#else
    NOT_USED(test_result, args...);
#endif
}
```

Some comments:

1. If `_DEBUG` is not defined, the function becomes empty so it can be optimized out 100%
2. If you call the function with a side effect, the non-debug code still works:

   ```
    my_assert(c++ < --z, "the #define versions do not behave similarly");
   ```

   These side effects are clearly visible here. However, if you call a function, it could be really difficult to know whether something happens in the function which was not otherwise expected.

   There are ways to prevent such side effects from happening, though ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746324/ignore-side-effects-in-asserted-expression-in-c)). But all in all, in some cases, you need to call a function for the test and it may have a side effect and therefore needs to not be optimized out in non-debug code.
3. I use `abort()` because I know that stops the debugger properly, `std::terminate()` is the C++ way which in modern systems does the same thing, but if `std::terminate()` doesn't work for your debugger the `abort()` will.
4. The `NOT_USED()` is to avoid warnings about unused function parameters (if you don't have that warning, you may end up with expected bugs).
5. I have an implementation in [snapdev](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/tree/main/snapdev): see `safe_assert.h` and `not_used.h`.

Answer (score 0):

going along with Konrad Rudolf's answer you can do it a bit more concise with

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ASSERT(condition,...) assert( \
    condition|| \
    (fprintf(stderr,__VA_ARGS__)&&fprintf(stderr," at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__)) \
);
```

which also works in C,

it works using the general idea from some of the answers to the question you linked, but the macro allows it to be a little more flexible