# How to exit an android NDK application

Tags: c++, android-ndk, exit

I'm making my own assert macro using Android NDK in C++ like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767883/1850223) answer, but there is an `std::exit` function that can not be used in Android. Is there some alternative like `std::exit` in Android?

Comment: C++ specifically says *Finally, control is returned to the host environment.* If a hosted implementation does not do this, it is non-conforming.

Comment: I just changed the std::exit function to assert(0) and it works

Comment: Have you tried `std::terminate`? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/429798ff636b0553e4ff3c692067718caa9c454e/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc

Comment: @Dannie It works just like assert(0), but std::terminate seems to be better choice. If you like you can convert your comment to an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had a similar requirement and found `std::terminate` works. In particular, on iOS (and quite likely Android) it causes a "forced" crash which Application Performance Management Tools (aka Crash Loggers) like Crashlytics would pick up and report.

- Evidence that Android handles std::terminate: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/429798ff636b0553e4ff3c692067718caa9c454e/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc

### Additional Reference:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate

Comment: Is there a way that it would not look like a crash ? Right now I see a message "Unfortunately <MyApp> has stopped".
In my app, at some specific stage that requires a restart of the app, I want to just terminate the app as soon as it is paused. Like a forced jettison...

Comment: In some case, `std::terminate()` just crashes the caller thread instead of quitting the app. I finally have to resort to the C API `exit()`.