# How to guide GCC optimizations based on assertions without runtime cost?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, assert, compiler-optimization

I have a macro used all over my code that in debug mode does:

```cpp
#define contract(condition) \
    if (!(condition)) \
        throw exception("a contract has been violated");
```

... but in release mode:

```cpp
#define contract(condition) \
    if (!(condition)) \
        __builtin_unreachable();
```

What this does over an `assert()` is that, in release builds, the compiler can heavily optimize the code thanks to UB propagation.

For example, testing with the following code:

```cpp
int foo(int i) {
    contract(i == 1);
    return i;
}

// ...

foo(0);
```

... throws an exception in debug mode, but produces assembly for an unconditional `return 1;` in release mode:

```
foo(int):
    mov  eax, 1
    ret
```

The condition, and everything that depended on it, has been optimized out.

My issue arises with more complex conditions. When compiler cannot *prove* that the condition has no side effect, it does not optimize it out, which is a runtime penalty compared to not using the contract.

Is there a way to express that the condition in the contract has no side effect, so that it is *always* optimized out?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144609/discussion-on-question-by-lyingonthesky-how-to-guide-gcc-optimizations-based-on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to force optimize out code as-if it was dead-code, because GCC has to always be complaint with the standard.

On the other hand the expression can be checked to not have any side effects by using the attribute `error` which will show an error whenever a function's call could not be optimized out.

An example of a macro that checks whatever is optimized out and does UB propagation:

```
#define _contract(condition) \
    {
        ([&]() __attribute__ ((noinline,error ("contract could not be optimized out"))) {
            if (condition) {} // using the condition in if seem to hide `unused` warnings.
        }());
        if (!(condition))
            __builtin_unreachable();
    }
```

The error attribute does not work without optimization (so this macro can only be used for release\optimization mode compilation).
Note that the error that indicates whatever the contract has side effects is shown during linkage.

[A test that shows an error with unoptimizable contract.](https://godbolt.org/g/Lfc5wX)

[A test that optimizes out a contract but, does UB propagation with it.](https://godbolt.org/g/S75fvS)

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way to express that the condition in the contract has no side effect, so that it is always optimized out?

Not likely.

It's known that you cannot take a big collection of assertions, turn them into assumptions (via `__builtin_unreachable`) and expect good results (e.g. [Assertions Are Pessimistic, Assumptions Are Optimistic](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1096) by John Regehr).

Some clues:

- CLANG, while already having the `__builtin_unreachable` intrinsic, introduced [__builtin_assume](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions) exactly for this purpose.
- [N4425 - Generalized Dynamic Assumptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4425.pdf)<sup>(*)</sup> notes that:

  > GCC does not explicitly provide a general assumption facility, but general assumptions can be encoded using a combination of control flow and the `__builtin_unreachable` intrinsic
  >
  > ...
  >
  > The existing implementations that provide generic assumptions use some keyword in the implementation­reserved identifier space (`__assume`, `__builtin_assume`, etc.). Because the expression argument is not evaluated (side effects are discarded), specifying this in terms of a special library function (e.g. `std::assume`) seems difficult.
- The Guidelines Support Library ([GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert), hosted by Microsoft, but in no way Microsoft specific) has "merely" this code:

  ```
  #ifdef _MSC_VER
  #define GSL_ASSUME(cond) __assume(cond)
  #elif defined(__clang__)
  #define GSL_ASSUME(cond) __builtin_assume(cond)
  #elif defined(__GNUC__)
  #define GSL_ASSUME(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : __builtin_unreachable())
  #else
  #define GSL_ASSUME(cond) static_cast<void>(!!(cond))
  #endif
  ```

  and notes that:

  ```
  // GSL_ASSUME(cond)
  //
  // Tell the optimizer that the predicate cond must hold. It is unspecified
  // whether or not cond is actually evaluated.
  ```

---

<sub>*) Paper [rejected](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-closed.html#179): EWG's guidance was to provide the functionality within the proposed contract facilities.</sub>

Comment: May I please know what "cond" does and where it is declared?

Comment: @jack_1729 `cond` is the input parameter of a function-like macro (take a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html). `GSL_ASSUME` expects a boolean expression/condition (`cond`).

Answer (score 11):

So, not an answer, but some interesting results which might lead somewhere.

I ended up with the following toy code:

```
#define contract(x) \
    if (![&]() __attribute__((pure, noinline)) { return (x); }()) \
        __builtin_unreachable();

bool noSideEffect(int i);

int foo(int i) {
    contract(noSideEffect(i));

    contract(i == 1);

    return i;
}
```

You can [follow along at home](https://godbolt.org/g/ihkiI8), too ;)

`noSideEffect` is the function which we know has no side effects, but the compiler doesn't.
It went like this:

1. GCC has `__attribute__((pure))` to mark a function as having no side effect.
2. Qualifying `noSideEffect` with the `pure` attribute removes the function call completely. Nice!
3. But we cannot modify the declaration of `noSideEffect`. So how about wrapping its call inside a function that is itself `pure`? And since we are trying to make a self-contained macro, a lambda sounds good.
4. Surprisingly, that doesn't work... unless we add `noinline` to the lambda! I suppose that the optimizer inlines the lambda first, losing the `pure` attribute on the way, before considering optimizing out the call to `noSideEffect`. With `noinline`, in a somewhat counter-intuitive way, the optimizer is able to wipe everything out. Great!
5. However, there are two issues now: with the `noinline` attribute, the compiler generates a body for each lambda, even if they are never used. Meh -- the linker will probably be able to throw them away anyway.
   But more importantly... We actually lost the optimizations that `__builtin_unreachable()` had enabled :(

To sum it up, you can remove or put back `noinline` in the snippet above, and end up with one of these results:

**With `noinline`**

```
; Unused code
foo(int)::{lambda()#2}::operator()() const:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax], 1
        sete    al
        ret
foo(int)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rax]
        jmp     noSideEffect(int)

; No function call, but the access to i is performed
foo(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

**Without `noinline`**

```
; No unused code
; Access to i has been optimized out,
; but the call to `noSideEffect` has been kept.
foo(int):
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    noSideEffect(int)
        mov     eax, 1
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Comment: I played with this toy quite a bit, I think it's a bug in GCC that it strips the `pure` attribute when it's inlining it, thanks for the knowledge there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++23, this is possible using the [`[[assume]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/assume). This attribute makes it undefined behavior if the given condition would not evaluate to `true`: For example:

```cpp
// define constract(...) conditionally
#if !defined(NDEBUG)
  #define contract(...) ((__VA_ARGS__) ? void() : \
                                         throw ::std::logic_error("contract violated"))

// feature testing macro to avoid warnings for unknown attributes
#elif __has_cpp_attribute(assume) >= 202207L
  #define contract(...) [[assume(__VA_ARGS__)]] // <<< C++23 ASSUME HERE

// clang has a similar feature as a compiler intrinsic
#elif defined(__clang__)
  #define contract(...) __builtin_assume(__VA_ARGS__)

// fallback case, might want to add more detections
#else
  #define contract(...) ((__VA_ARGS__) ? void() : __builtin_unreachable())
#endif
```

We can then use `contract` as usual:

```
int foo(int i) {
    contract(i == 1);
    return i;
}
```

This compiles to:

```
foo(int):
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

It may take some time for all compilers to implement this. As of the time of writing, only GCC 13 supports this.
Also keep in mind that the compiler's ability to use assumptions is limited. It cannot infer information from arbitrarily complex expressions, so use expressions which are as simple as possible.

*See also: [C++23 Compiler Support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23)*