# Is it possible to make MSVC's __assume(0) aka std::unreachable() actually optimize?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, micro-optimization, assumption

Compiling the following code with MSVC

```
#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <utility>

static auto bit_width(unsigned long x) {
    unsigned long i;
    _BitScanReverse(&i, x);
    ++i;
    if (x == 0) { i = 0; }
    return i;
}

auto foo(unsigned long x) {
    __assume(x > 0);
    return bit_width(x);
}

auto bar(unsigned long x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return bit_width(x);
    } else {
        std::unreachable();  // implemented as __assume(0) in MSVC
    }
}
```

[generates](https://godbolt.org/z/zo7hqcd1a) the following, where `foo` got optimized and `bar` didn't (compiling to the same asm as the general-case function that checks for zero).

```
bit_width(unsigned long)
        bsr     eax, ecx
        xor     edx, edx
        inc     eax
        test    ecx, ecx
        cmovne  edx, eax
        mov     eax, edx
        ret     0

foo(unsigned long) PROC
        bsr     eax, ecx
        inc     eax
        ret     0

bar(unsigned long) PROC
        bsr     eax, ecx
        xor     edx, edx
        inc     eax
        test    ecx, ecx
        cmovne  edx, eax
        mov     eax, edx
        ret     0
```

MSVC's documentation [suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/assume?view=msvc-170) that `__assume(0)` as an "unreachable" assertion should help with optimization, but I can't actually make it do this.

Is it possible to use `std::unexpected()` to optimize code such as the above on MSVC? If so, how?

---

`__assume(x>0)` works but isn't portable; [Clang has an equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493968/reproducing-clangs-builtin-assume-for-gcc) `__builtin_assume`.  These are different from GNU C `__builtin_expect(x>0, 1)` which would only hint the compiler that's *usually* the case, like `[[likely]]`, not a promise which can affect correctness.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Yeah I got stuck on comparing `__assume()` to `std::unreachable()` and missed the difference in args.  I edited to help future readers avoid the same error when skimming, by explicitly saying that MSVC `__assume(0)` *is* `std::unreachable` (a fact I didn't know and wasn't expecting when trying to understand the question yesterday), and changing the code comment so it can't be misread as saying that the whole if/else/unreachable structure is equivalent to using `__assume(x>0)`.

Comment: It does work in some cases in current MSVC, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/xan93v4a1 is the example from their docs, fixed up to be less weird (not `main` so no implicit return 0) and to use the portable C++23 `std::unreachable()` so we can compare with clang.  So the warning about using `__assume` wrong leading to wrong code isn't just applicable to old compiler versions, it does make a difference still.  Just not here, because MSVC's optimizer isn't smart enough to derive value-range information from this `if` and apply it to a different `if`, at least not in this case.

Comment: (Removed my incorrect first comment.  https://godbolt.org/z/Er4rG5s15 compares the same code with GCC and clang, which do optimize.  And in case anyone's wondering, `bsr` leaves its destination register unmodified in the input=0 case, but the `_BitScanReverse` treats the `int*` operand as write-only and doesn't init the destination reg.  So that's not an option.  If we had BMI1, `32-lzcnt(x)` would give the 1+BSR result we want, including for `lzcnt(0) = 32`